# Different category structure and a subnet of products

Tags: magento2

A merchant selling tools want a specialized shop for a specific profession. It requires a different category
structure and a subnet of products.
How do you set up a specialized shop in Magento in addition to the main store?
1)Create a new store with its own root category and store view within the same. Assign products to the
store view
2) Create a new website, store, and store and keep the same category. Assign the required categories and
products to the website.
3) Create a new store view with its own root category within the main store. Assign products to the new
categories tree
4) Create a new website with one store and its own root category and one store view Assign the required
products to the new website.

What will be the ans for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

4. Create a new website with one store and its own root category and one store view Assign the required products to the new website.